# How to group elements by n in Angular's ng-repeat with Slick.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, slick.js

My elements are result of ng-repeat inside the slick div. Now, I wanted is to group them by two per div inside the carousel.

I tried this method using JQuery's slice and wrap but it only works with slick if the divs are not being ng-repeat:

```
var divs = $(".ebookimg");
for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i+=2) {
   j = i + 1; 
  divs.slice(i, i+2).wrapAll("<div class='ebookcont'></div>");
}
```

Code originally from here: http://jsfiddle.net/RQNrt/

The divs on that jsfiddle are all mentioned and not by ng-repeat... also as each division will be included as 1 slide for slick.

Wanted output:

| Book 1 Book 2 | | Book 3 Book 4 | | Book 5 |

If the element is not equal to 2 it will still create a div for the excess.

Here are my codes:

View:

```
<section id="members_ebook" class="npm">
    <div class="container-fluid npm">
        <div class="row npm">
            <div class="col-sm-12 npm">
                <slick settings="slickConfig">
                    <div class="ebookcont" ng-repeat="ebook in ebooks">
                        <img class="ebookimg" ng-src="{{ ebook.url }}">
                    </div>
                </slick>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Controller:

```
.controller('EbookController', function($scope, EbookSample) {
    $scope.imagesURL = '/images/';

    $scope.ebooks = EbookSample.all();

    $scope.slickConfig = {
        enabled: true,
        autoplay: true, 
        infinite: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 1000,
        arrows: false,
        mobileFirst: true
    };
});
```

Comment: Is the http://jsfiddle.net/RQNrt/ JS Fiddle an illustration of your problem or the code you used as inspiration?

Comment: the code i used for separating elements by group in a div and worked with slick. but when i used ng-repeat for series of divs it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you fork the JsFiddle to show the problem.

Comment: sorry but i'm not used to jsfiddle